# Integrating Kotlin with Python

Tags: python, kotlin, architecture

I have an existing Python Django application. Now as it has grown a little bigger, I would like to write some business logic in Kotlin. Is there a way to integrate those two languages? Of course it can be done with microservices, but this would add too much complexity.

Comment: Maybe you could make it work if you use Jython on the JVM. But I don't see how that would be less complex than just having 2 microservices.

Comment: Not much detail but slightly relevant: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/call-kotlin-from-python-jython/2481

Comment: Jython is a great idea, however, it does not support Python 3. Since the last news on their official website were added in May 2015, I am not sure, whether Python 3 support is coming in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

I found this sample in Kotlin Native repository of python extension:

https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/tree/master/samples/python_extension